# How to refer another value from a foreign model that is not a primary key in JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am building a **sales model table** e I want to put in my table the Id of a product and the name.

My Product Model:

```
public class ProductModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long idProduct;
    
    @NotNull
    private String nameProduct;
}
```

My Sales Table:

```
public class SalesModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private idSales

    @ManyToOne
    private ProductModel productId;
    
    private ProductModel productName;
```

How can I refer the product name in the code below??

```
private ProductModel productName;
```

I am using Spring,JPA and MYSQL

Comment: Why would you refer to the `productName`? this would be unnecessary redundancy.

Comment: This is not a correct approach.
You already have a relation to `ProductModel` , you can fetch whatever you like to fetch inside ProductModel via 'productId'. 
I think  what you are trying to store is just the Id and name of ProductModel .